# ¿Cómo cargar datos en un UITableView?

Tags: json, swift2

¿Cómo puedo cargar datos en un `TableView` desde un archivo `.json` con `Swift 2`?

Me imagino que porque este código que encontré esta hecho en Xcode 6.1 con iOS 8.1 y quiero suponer que ha cambiado la sintaxis, no?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Arturo!, trata de mostrar que es lo que has intentado previamente!

Answer (score 1):

Como dicen los compañeros, deberías probar algo antes y si no consigues implementarlo, te podremos ayudar. No obstante, te doy un punto de partida. Todo depende de donde venga el JSON, si es un fichero local guardado en el bundle, si está guardado en el directorio de archivos (por ejemplo carpeta documents) de la aplicación o si es un fichero de Internet.

Para leer un fichero JSON guardado en el bundle por ejemplo, debes hacer algo así:

```
if let pathToBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myjson", ofType:"json") {
    if let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile:pathToBundle, options:.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error:nil) {
        if let jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:nil) as? NSDictionary {
            // aquí ya tienes el contenido del json en jsonResult
        }
    }
}
```

`jsonResult` contiene un objeto `NSDictionary` que deberías usar para acto seguido mostrar los datos en un `UITableView`. Hay miles de tutoriales sobre como mostrar datos en un `TableView`, solo tienes que hacer una sencilla búsqueda en Google. Como [esta](http://bit.ly/1P9XyBV) por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

*Bienvenido*, desafortunadamente nosotros no te podemos ayudar mucho si no muestras tu código o lo que intentaste de hacer. Pero te voy a dar un ejemplo y la idea general del JSON en Swift, junto con una referencia a una pagina para que puedas aprender.

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es definir el array que se utilizará para guardar y leer los datos. Por ejemplo vamos a definir el array string `JSONDatos`

```
JSONDatos var: Array <String> = Array <String> ()
```

El `viewDidLoad ()` es la función que llamará cuanto el punto de vista ha sido cargado. Adentro de la función deberías llamar una variable para los datos de una website, vamos a llamarle `coje_datos_de_website`

```
JSONDatos var: Array <String> = Array <String> ()
anular func viewDidLoad () {
       super.viewDidLoad ()
       coje_datos_de_website ("http://www.google.com")
}
```

**Referencia:**

- [Tutorial – conecta tu app a un servicio JSON en Swift y #Alamofire #swiftlang #api](http://programadores-ios.net/tutorial-conecta-tu-app-a-un-servicio-json-en-swift-y-alamofire-swiftlang-api/)

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberías ocuparte de cargar el JSON y tenerlo estructurado en un Diccionario, Array, meterlo en coredata o como prefieras, y después ocúpate de cargar la tabla. Tienes que tener en cuenta, como te dicen, donde tienes el JSON, si es en local, pues lo puedes cargar en el `viewDidLoad` y luego se te cargara la tabla sin problemas, pero si lo tienes que procesar en otro hilo, ten en cuenta que la tabla se va a cargar y todavía no tienes los datos, asi que tendras que hacer un `tableView.reloadData()` una vez hayas procesado el JSON